# Is there a speed disadvantage to API-centric websites

Tags: php, api, curl, model-view-controller

I'm building an MVC web application (let's call it xyz.com). I want it to also support mobile apps via an API on the same server (let's call this api.xyz.com).

I'm confused about how to structure the web app vs. the API:

1. Should the web app use the API to query the database? Or should it perform them independently (like using a Model)? I mean, should the flow be (User > Controller > API > Database) or (User > Controller > Model > Database)?
2. If we use the APIs to query the database, how would you query the API? Would you use something like cURL?
3. If we use cURL, wouldn't that slow down the process? (As we are making a second request from the controller)? What's the ideal way to do this?

I've tried reading up on API-centric web apps, but there's not too much information about this on the net.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. I don't think that API should be between Controller and Database. API would use Model too normally. API should be in the routing level of your app as an entity and from there to controller probably (depends on your structure). API is just an endpoint receiving requests and sending responses.
2,3 . If the API is in routing level, if you call it from mobile app you would probably perform cURL request, if same API method is to be called from your website, you just need a url to that endpoint (or form if it is for post request etc.)

Comment: Thanks @DimitrisKontoulis, I agree with your points. My API is in fact in the routing level. So please tell me if the following scenario is correct: User submits the form to xyz.com... xyz.com uses a cURL request to api.xyz.com to perform the action... api.xyz.com returns json response to xyz.com... xyz.com returns html content to user - is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since I have not enough points to comment I'll just leave my thoughts here.

1) I would make the web app use the API for 2 main reasons:

- I don't like having multiples components accessing my database, you'll most likely have a lot of duplicate code on the data extraction and if you have a lot of filtering you might make mistakes and they'll behave differently.
- I believe that (if I'm wrong please correct me) it'll be easier to increase performances on the app rather than the database. Since the API will handle resources it'll be easier to cache things than a full HTML web page.

2) To query the API I would most likely use composer and find a nice HTTP library, not sure which one though since I didn't use php in a while (symfony's and laravel's are quite nice if I remember well).

3) Yeah it might slow down the process a little but I believe it won't be enough to be noticed by the user. As I said above, with a correct cache handling you'll do just fine.

Hope having my thoughts on this can help, if I was wrong somewhere please feel free to correct me in the comments below (Don't know if I'll be able to respond tho... :s).

Have a nice day !

Comment: I totally agree with this post (and this is actually more of an answer than a comment anyway). One more benefit from this is that the API and the website doesn't need to be on the same server, or even on the same network. However, if they are on the same server, the request time for the API calls from the website would be more or less instant.

Comment: And if you're looking for a stable, well maintained standalone HTTP-library, I recommend [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle), but that's just my opinion. There are a few good options out there.

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson.. this was really helpful - my api is on the same server, so that's good for me

Comment: Thanks Youcef, I'll use caching.. your answer was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You really want to know the difference between an *n-tier* architecture and a single-tier architecture. An n-tier architecture is comprised of several tiers, which are connected via an internal protocol and API. E.g.:

```
  backend                                      frontend
   data   --- HTTP server --- HTTP client --- application --- HTTP server --- browser
application
```

You could have many more tiers in there. Those tiers can all run on the same physical machine, but they still talk to each other over HTTP; more likely you'd want to run each tier on a different machine though.

Yes, this will obviously incur some overhead in talking to your database backend over HTTP instead of doing it within the same PHP process. However, this is offset by:

1. Caching is built-in in this architecture. If you make proper use of HTTP caching by using a fully capable HTTP server *and client* and are using the HTTP cache mechanism well, you can reduce the absolute amount of queries made enormously. Practically you'd set up a reverse proxy on the web server on your frontend server, so your queries go *PHP → curl → web server reverse proxy → backend server*. If the reverse proxy is caching properly, that's where the chain often stops, which can be much faster than executing the actual query on the database. If the backend server is using HTTP caching effectively, it too can probably often respond with a simple `304 Not Modified`, which is also very fast.
2. Load is distributed among more machines, which speeds up each individual machine. If your frontend servers can largely work with cached data without needing to bother the database, the database is much faster for the queries that it *does* need to handle. You can also scale up your frontend servers to many instances, each of which is faster because it has less load.

These are the advantages of such an architecture. The further advantage is that you can also directly expose your internal HTTP API to the outside world (again, reverse proxies make a lot of sense here). If you're not using an internal HTTP API, you have to write:

1. A controller and view which gets data from the model and renders to HTML.
2. A controller and view which gets data from the model and renders to JSON (or whatever).

To some degree controllers can be reused and simply the view switched out, if everything else is the same, but often you'll find that you need to duplicate each logical "thing" to be served as HTML in one case and JSON in another, and you need to keep those in sync.